# My own singleton using Kotlin, a little smaller than others

Tags: android, kotlin

I found in stack a lot of topic's about singleton. But in my opinion, singleton in Kotlin can be simpler:

```
class SingletonTwo private constructor(){

    var myAge: Int = 16

    companion object {
        val ourInstance = SingletonTwo()
    }

}
```

Now I can get access in other class to this variable myAge:

```
var abc: Int
abc = SingletonTwo.ourInstance.myAge
```

Something is wrong here ? This singleton is a little smaller than in other subjects on stack.
Please someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "This singleton is a little smaller than in other subjects on stack" -- perhaps those "other subjects" solve other problems that your singleton does not, such as thread synchronization. Since you did not link to these "other subjects", we cannot draw comparisons.

Comment: ok, I understand, but this singleton is real "singleton" ?  I'm just starting to learn and do not want to learn bad habits

Answer (score 8):

Declaring something with the `object` keyword instead of `class` makes it a singleton on its own:

```
object SingletonTwo {
    var myAge: Int = 16
}
```

In this case, you can access the variable like so:

```
var abc: Int = SingletonTwo.myAge
```

You can see the docs about [object declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) which also notes that they should be used to easily create singletons.

Comment: but in this way, we can use everywhere this object, object should have a simply name, so in big app, we can use it by accident

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for - you'd also have the instance in your solution available from everywhere. Plus, you could apply [visibility modifiers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) to either of them, for example you could restrict your singleton to a single module with `internal`.